# selenium PhantomJS send_keys doesn't work

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I am using selenium and PhantomJS for testing. I followed Selenium's simple usage, but send_keys doesn't work on PhantomJS, it works on Firefox. Why? I have to use `button.click()` instead?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys

reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()

driver.get("http://www.python.org/")
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("q")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("python")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
# button = driver.find_element_by_id('submit')
# button.click()
print driver.title
print driver.page_source
driver.close()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I highly suspect it's just timing issue.

Selenium's `click()` will wait for page to load if it is redirected after clicking, while `send_key()` doesn't wait. (PhantomJS is headless, which is faster than Firefox)

Please try add some sleep like `time.sleep(5)` after `elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)`, before `print driver.title`, and see if you can get the result you want.

In real testing project, you just need to use WebDriverWait until `driver.title` equals to the value you want.

Comment: I just came across the same problem. Yes, it is a timing issue, but still Keys.RETURN did not work for me, I needed to use Keys.ENTER. I got the idea from https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver/issues/249