# Selenium/PhantomJS: Can not send_keys to input (TypeError - undefined is not a function)

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

My simple code code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
# Maximized the window to make sure the element will be displayed
browser.maximize_window() 
browser.get('https://banhang.shopee.vn/account/signin')
# Delay a few seconds to allow all javascript to be loaded properly
sleep(5)
tag = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/div[3]/input')
tag.send_keys('1234567890')
```

The exception being raised:

```
 File "/miniconda2/envs/flecom/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 347, in send_keys
    self._execute(Command.SEND_KEYS_TO_ELEMENT, {'value': keys_to_typing(value)})
  File "/miniconda2/envs/flecom/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 494, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/miniconda2/envs/flecom/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/miniconda2/envs/flecom/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 163, in check_response
    raise exception_class(value)
WebDriverException: Message: TypeError - undefined is not a function (evaluating '_getTagName(currWindow).toLowerCase()')
```

If I change `webdriver.PhantomJS()` to `webdriver.Chrome()`, it worked without any exceptions. What did I do wrong?

Some other info:

- PhantomJS v2.1
- Selenium 3.0.2
- Python 2.7.13
- Ubuntu 16.04 64bit

PS: I also tried to `click` on the element before `send_keys`, but it did not make any differences.

Comment: Maybe add some `time.sleep` will solve the issue, look at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17800573/selenium-phantomjs-send-keys-doesnt-work)

Comment: @Arman thanks for your attention, but adding `sleep` after `send_keys` doesn't help, because the exception is raised right after `send_keys`. On the other hand, there is already a `sleep` before `send_keys`.

Answer (score 0):

Trying reverting to PhantomJS 1.9.8

I had this same error using PhantomJS 2.1.1 and reverting solved it for me.